# TouchableHighlight onPress fires automatically on navigation

Tags: android, ios, react-native, navigation

I have two views in my react native app. and im using `reactnavigtion` to go to second view. below is that code.

```
 <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigate('Detail', { title: 'Text' })}>
                            <View style={styles.box} >

                            </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
```

and above code works fine. in second view i added link to open up in the web browser when user tap on it.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton('http://www.someurl.com')}>
                        <View style={styles.box} >

                        </View>
 </TouchableHighlight>
```

and following is the method.

```
_onPressButton(url){
            const uri = url;
            Linking.openURL(uri).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
        }
```

Problem is when i click to goto second view. it automatically fires the second view `_onPressButton` function as well. this happening in both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax you're using will invoke that function on every render which is why it's firing immediately. You have to either put it into an anonymous function or create a method for it.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._onPressButton('http://www.someurl.com')}>
```

or define a method that uses that argument

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.navigateToSomeURL}>
```

Comment: Awesome. i didnt know about that. Thank you very much